# Simple linear regression in R with many x varibales and one y. Only write one model and not for each x and y combination?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I would like to analyse many x variables (400 variables) against one y variable (1 variable). However I do not want to write for each and every x variable a new model. Is it possible to write one model which than checks all x variables with y in R-Studio?

Comment: Do you mean independently of each other? Or including them in the same model?

Comment: y ( dependent variable) and x (independent variable). Aim is simple regression where each x individually is compared to y. No multiple linear regression. x variables sometimes are dependent on each other but in this case does not matter.                                                                                                                    model.1 = lm(y ~ x1, data = dataset)

model.2 = lm(y ~ x2, data = dataset)

Comment: Have provided options for both below

Comment: The ExhaustiveSearch package can  run subsets of independent variables. Specify the `combsUpTo=1` argument to only consider subsets of one independent variable at a time.  Also you may be interested in the abess package which will consider all subsets using a penalty to force sparsity in the coefficient vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data frame is DF,

```
regs <- list()
for (v in setdiff(names(DF), "y")) {
  fm <- eval(parse(text = sprintf("y ~ %s", v)))
  regs[[v]] <- lm(fm, data=DF)
}
```

Now you have all simple regression results in the `regs` list.

Example:

```
## Generate data
n <- 1000
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame(y = rnorm(n))
for (j in seq(400)) DF[[paste0('x',j)]] <- rnorm(n)
## Now data ready

dim(DF)
# [1] 1000 401
head(names(DF))
# [1] "y"  "x1" "x2" "x3" "x4" "x5"
tail(names(DF))
# [1] "x395" "x396" "x397" "x398" "x399" "x400"

regs <- list()
for (v in setdiff(names(DF), "y")) {
  fm <- eval(parse(text = sprintf("y ~ %s", v)))
  regs[[v]] <- lm(fm, data=DF)
}

head(names(regs))
# [1] "x1" "x2" "x3" "x4" "x5" "x6"

r2s <- sapply(regs, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared)
head(r2s, 3)
#           x1           x2           x3 
# 0.0000409755 0.0024376111 0.0005509134
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach where we use a function that regresses all variables in a data frame on a dependent variable from the same data frame that is passed as an argument to the function.

We use `lapply()` to drive `lm()` because it will return the resulting model objects as a list, and we are able to easily name the resulting list so we can extract models by independent variable name.

```
regList <- function(dataframe,depVar) {
     indepVars <- names(dataframe)[!(names(dataframe) %in% depVar)]
     
     modelList <- lapply(indepVars,function(x){
          lm(dataframe[[depVar]] ~ dataframe[[x]],data=dataframe)
     })
     # name list elements based on independent variable names 
     names(modelList) <- indepVars
     modelList
}
```

We demonstrate the function with the `mtcars` data frame, assigning the `mpg` column as the dependent variable.

```
modelList <- regList(mtcars,"mpg")
```

At this point the `modelList` object contains 10 models, one for each variable in the `mtcars` data frame other than `mpg`.  We can access the individual models by independent variable name, or by index.

```
# print the model where cyl is independent variable 
summary(modelList[["cyl"]])
```

...and the output:

```
> summary(modelList[["cyl"]])

Call:
lm(formula = dataframe[[depVar]] ~ dataframe[[x]], data = dataframe)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9814 -2.1185  0.2217  1.0717  7.5186 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     37.8846     2.0738   18.27  < 2e-16 ***
dataframe[[x]]  -2.8758     0.3224   -8.92 6.11e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.206 on 30 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7262,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7171 
F-statistic: 79.56 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 6.113e-10
```

### Extracting the content

Saving the output in a `list()` enables us to do things like find the model with the highest R^2 without having to use [vgrep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_inspection#Humorous_terminology).

First, we extract the `r.squared` value from each model summary and save the results to a vector.

```
r.squareds <- unlist(lapply(modelList,function(x) summary(x)$r.squared))
```

Because we used `names()` to name elements in the original list, R automatically saves the variable names to the element names of the vector. This comes in handy when we sort the vector by descending order of R^2 and print the first element of the resulting vector.

```
r.squareds[order(r.squareds,decreasing=TRUE)][1]
```

...and the winner (not surprisingly) is `wt`.

```
> r.squareds[order(r.squareds,decreasing=TRUE)][1]
       wt 
0.7528328
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include them in the models separately, you can just loop over the x variables and add them into the model on each iteration. For example:

```
x_variables = list("x_var1", "x_var2", "x_var3", "x_var4", ...)
for(x in x_variables){
model <- lm(y_variable ~ x, data = df)
summary(model)
}
```

You can fill in the elipses in the code above with all your other x variables. I hope for your sake that there is some kind of naming convention you can exploit to select the variables using a dplyr verb like `starts_with` or `contains`!

If you hope to include all the x variables in the same model, you just add them in as you normally would. For example (assuming you want to use an OLS, but the same premise would work for other types):

```
model <- lm(y_variable ~ 
      x_var1, x_var2, x_var3, x_var4, ..., data = df)
summary(model)
```

Comment: Thank you fill check now.